# Web development

Tags: javascript, php, html, ruby-on-rails

First of all hi to all, I am new at web development and I have some questions. I have  started a web site few weeks ago(html,css,js) and now I don't know how to continue. what is the next step for my project and how can I practice without publish it in a server? Nowdays I am learning php and ruby but it is more complex to understand the back end of a web site.

Comment: You need to be more specific. We can't point you in the right direction without knowing what you want to accomplish.

Comment: You can run your own virtual server on your PC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have already started a website, add more functionalities to it. This way, you can enhance the project and at the same time learn new things as you develop. For example, if the project is in HTML, learn Bootstrap and implement the same to the project. You can publish various versions of the project. If you do not wish to publish, you can work on it locally too.

You mentioned that you are learning PHP. Why not just throw in some data to the HTML using PHP and perform some CRUD operations on it? That would be a great way to learn!

https://www.w3schools.com/ is a great website to learn.

Wish you Goodluck and I hope I helped!

Comment: Thank you for your responses. Like I said before I'm new and I don't know how to express my questions right. My apologies and I'll try to be more specific next time